# Django select inherited model in a single query

Tags: django, django-models

Let's Assume I have a parent and a child tables which are implemented via inheritance in django.

**models.py**

```
class A(models.Model)
 a = CharField()

class B(A):
 b = CharField()
```

Now I want to select column `b` from table `B` I execute:

```
B.objects.only('b').get(id=4)
```

But this statement queries database 2 times:

```sql
SELECT `b`.`a_ptr_id`, `b`.`b` FROM `b` WHERE `b`.`a_ptr_id` = 4; args=(4,)
SELECT `a`.`a`, `b`.`a_id` FROM `b` INNER JOIN `a` ON (`b`.`a_ptr_id` = `b`.`id`) WHERE `b`.`a_ptr_id` = 4; args=(4,)
```

How do I generate SINGLE query like `select b from b where a_ptr_id = ?` using django models?

**I want to query database one single time!**

Comment: that statement only gives line one of the 2 sql queries, you should get the second one when you do `B.objects.only('a').get(id=4)`, maybe you looped over the db connection and printed all the sql queries?

Comment: I just created new app with exactly the same model I describe above. When I execute `B.objects.only('b').get(id=1)` it runs the first query. But as soon as I access field `b` (e.g. `print(b.b)`) it runs 2nd query.

Comment: Here's the proof: download `https://static.pychat.org/mysite2.zip`, unpack, specify your database source in `settings.py` (can't get logs work sqlight), execute `./manage.py makemigrations mysite2`,  `./manage.py migrate`, `./manage.py runserver 8888`, open `localhost:8888/ad` url in and check logs from database.

Comment: hmm, what's the sql when you check from the django connection?

Comment: That one I posted in my question `'SELECT 'a'.'a', 'b'.'a_id' FROM 'b' INNER JOIN 'a' ON ('b'.'a_ptr_id' = 'b'.'id') WHERE 'b'.'a_ptr_id' = 4; args=(4,)'`

Comment: so the db log shows different query than django connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148252/discussion-between-deathangel908-and-hassenpy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that only 1 query was generated.  The 2nd query was caused because I checked all of this in debug mode. My IDE evaluated the object automatically which led to querying the database with

```
SELECT `a`.`a`, `b`.`a_id` FROM `b` INNER JOIN `a` ON (`b`.`a_ptr_id` = `b`.`id`) WHERE `b`.`a_ptr_id` = 4;
```